# Javascript cookie used to alter display of divs

Tags: javascript, css, cookies

I would like to be able to display a large promotion for the first page view, then after that only show a minimized promotion that is expandable. It appears that my conditional in the javascript does not change the style of the divs. The alert dialogs (placed for testing) do work and the cookie appears to be functioning. I am a javascript newbie.

Any help is appreciated.

```
<script>
if (document.cookie.indexOf('visited=true') == -1) {
var oneDay = 1000*60*60*24*1;
var expires = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() + oneDay);
document.cookie = "visited=true;expires=" + expires.toUTCString();
alert('We can show the large promo because this is the first page view for today.');
} else {
alert('We\'ve already shown the large promo, we will show a much smaller expandable promo.');
document.getElementById('promo').style.display='none';
document.getElementById('promo-reduced').style.display='block';
}
</script>

<div id="promo-reduced" style="display:none;">
<a onclick="show();"> <img src="/images/small_icon.gif" height="26" width="48" border="0" align="left" />Learn about this product.</a>
</div>

<div id="promo" style="display:block;">
<a onclick="conceal();">Close</a> 
<a href="/learn-more.html" target="_blank" onclick="conceal();"><img src="/images/large-promo.jpg" border="0" /></a><br />
</div>
```

Comment: Your script executes before the HTML is placed on the page. You should place the above script below the HTML code. I wish you execute the script on `document.onload`

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears to work, but the JavaScript is firing before the DOM is ready. Try placing your script after the content inside the  body.

Comment: You guys were both correct, the script was loading before the DOM.

I first added a body onload and that worked, but settled on wrapping my code within a document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { -- which was added to the first script.